# Barplot for a count of elements from different columns - guidance

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, matplotlib, charts

According to a given dataset, I need to give 3 barplots which correspond to the 3 sites from the `Sites` column, `A1` `A2` or `A3`.

Each barplot should give the count of the outcome for each site. The outcome is what happened in the most right column between `PT1` and `PT4`, disregarding what happened left of it.

This is a choice between: `NOT_FINISHED` `NOT_TESTED` `TOO_LOW`, a number between `150` & `190` (seperated by 5, so 150, 155, 160...), or nothing.
If there is no entry in columns PT1 to PT4 for a given element (row) then nothing is counted.

Each barplot should therefore have 12 sticks, corresponding to the count of each possible outcome.

Below is an extract of my dataset.

I am new to all this, I am not asking for a direct solution necessarily but just some guidance on where to start if possible.

Using python 2.7, seaborn, pandas and matplotlib.

```
pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 'GF342',  1: 'IF874',  2: 'FH386',  3: 'KJ190',  4: 'TY748',  5: 'YT947',  6: 'DF063',  7: 'ET512',  8: 'GC714',  9: 'SD978',  10: 'EF472',  11: 'PL489',  12: 'AZ315',  13: 'OL821',  14: 'HN765',  15: 'ED589'}, 'Sites': {0: 'A1',  1: 'A3',  2: 'A1',  3: 'A3',  4: 'A3',  5: 'A2',  6: 'A3',  7: 'A1',  8: 'A2',  9: 'A3',  10: 'A1',  11: 'A2',  12: 'A1',  13: 'A1',  14: 'A3',  15: 'A1'}, 'NEW': {0: 'YES',  1: 'NO',  2: 'NO',  3: 'YES',  4: 'YES',  5: 'NO',  6: 'NO',  7: 'YES',  8: 'NO',  9: 'NO',  10: 'NO',  11: 'YES',  12: 'NO',  13: 'YES',  14: 'YES',  15: 'YES'}, 'YEAR': {0: 2021,  1: 2018,  2: 2019,  3: 2021,  4: 2021,  5: 2019,  6: 2019,  7: 2021,  8: 2018,  9: 2019,  10: 2018,  11: 2021,  12: 2018,  13: 2021,  14: 2021,  15: 2021}, 'PT1': {0: '',  1: 'NOT_TESTED',  2: '',  3: 'NOT_FINISHED',  4: '165',  5: '',  6: '180',  7: '145',  8: '155',  9: '',  10: '',  11: '',  12: 'TOO_LOW',  13: '150',  14: '155',  15: ''}, 'PT2': {0: '',  1: '',  2: '',  3: '',  4: '',  5: 'TOO_LOW',  6: '',  7: '',  8: '160',  9: 'TOO_LOW',  10: '',  11: '',  12: '',  13: '',  14: '',  15: ''}, 'PT3': {0: '',  1: 'TOO_LOW',  2: '',  3: 'TOO_LOW',  4: '',  5: '',  6: '',  7: '',  8: '',  9: '',  10: '',  11: 'NOT_FINISHED',  12: '',  13: '185',  14: '',  15: '165'}, 'PT4': {0: '',  1: '',  2: '',  3: '',  4: '',  5: 165.0,  6: '',  7: '',  8: '',  9: '',  10: '',  11: '',  12: 180.0,  13: '',  14: '',  15: ''}})
```

**EDIT:**

In other words, for each row, I need the program to check TP4 first, if TP4 has a value (`NOT_FINISHED` `NOT_TESTED` `TOO_LOW`, a number between `150` & `190` (seperated by 5, so 150, 155, 160...)) then it counts 1 for that and adds it to the barplot corresponding to the 'site'.
Then, it moves to the next row and repeats.

**However**, if no value was found in TP4 then it goes to TP3, TP2 etc till it finds something. If it finds nothing in all 4 columns then nothing is counted and we simply go to the next row.

I hope this clarification can help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you're using Python 2.7?

Comment: Not a good one, it is simply a constraint I have been given for this. I have no say in it

Answer (score 0):

Working solution with your df:

```
# make a list (x_labels) of all the possible values from Pi columns:
t = df[['PT1','PT2','PT3','PT4']].values
flat_list = [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]
flat_list = [x for x in flat_list if x != '']
x_labels = flat_list.copy()

# create bar plots:
for i,group in df.groupby('Sites'):
    t = group[['PT1','PT2','PT3','PT4']].values
    flat_list = [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]
    flat_list = [x for x in flat_list if x != '']
    unique, counts = np.unique(flat_list, return_counts=True)
    for label in x_labels:
        if label not in unique:
            unique = np.append(unique, label)
            counts = np.append(counts, 0)
    unique, counts = zip(*sorted(zip(unique, counts)))
    plt.bar(unique, counts)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.title(i)
    plt.show();
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helps. I get a 'nan' column which seems to be counting all the 'null' values. How can I get rid of that column as it is not useful? Also, this code seems to be outputting a plot only for A3, would this be because I'm on python 2.7?

Comment: Do you mean None column or empty string column?


plt.show(); in the loop separate the plots

Comment: In the bar plot, I get a stick called 'nan' with a very high value, I want to remove it. I will try to separate the plots in the loop, I'm not entirely sure on how that's done.

Comment: you cab use dropna() function, look up for it. or another way to drop nan values. and remove them before the plot.

Comment: flat_list = [x for x in flat_list if x is not np.nan ]    you can add this row after both of the flat_list rows. it suppose remove the nan (if the nan is a string modify np.nan to 'nan')

Comment: 'flat_list = [x for x in flat_list if x is not np.nan ]' fixed this particular issue

Comment: plt.figure() add this at the start of the loop and remove the : after the plt.show

Comment: did it work? if the solution helped, mark it.